# How do I read the cache of Chrome and Firefox programmatically on the Mac?

Tags: cocoa, macos, firefox, caching, google-chrome

**Background**

I want to access the cache of Chrome and Firefox in my Cocoa application. I need to get the HTML for pages accessed recently. Safari is a piece of cake - all this information is available in SQLite data stores, but not so in Chrome and Firefox.

**The Problem**

For Firefox, the cache is in /Library/Caches/Firefox/Profiles/xxx.default/Cache with filenames _CACHE_001_ _CACHE_002_ _CACHE_003_ and _CACHE_MAP_

For Chrome, the cache is in /Library/Caches/Google/Chrome/Default/Cache with filenames data_0 data_1 data_2 and data_3

**What I've tried**

The only article I can find that sheds any light on what format these caches are in [is here](http://www.securityfocus.com/infocus/1832). It recommends a Cache Viewer tool, but doesn't explain how one might do this programmatically.

**Questions**

1. Is there any way of reconstructing
   this data using command line tools
   or the Cocoa framework? Or is it
   much too low level?
2. Is there another way of getting at
   the HTML of recent web pages that I
   don't know about?

Comment: This might not be really helpful, but since both Firefox and Chromium are open source, it should definitely be possible to decode the format they use.

Comment: OMG. I can't believe I didn't think of that! It'll be a hassle, but it's a viable worst case scenario. Thanks for pointing out what should have been clear to me! :)

Comment: Bear in mind that even though Safari's cache is easy to read at the moment, you've got no guarantee it will remain in the same location and format in the future.

Comment: Yep, good point, Mike. I'm going to post a separate Stack Overflow question about this now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I can see is that suggested by Ole above, namely to look at the code from Chrome and Firefox and work out how they encode the cache.

I've since realised this is a huge coding challenge fraught with difficulties. I'm ditching this functionality and trying a simpler way.

Comment: Can you script Firefox / Chrome and use that to expose their internal API to your application?  Perhaps installing a Firefox plugin that reads the cache and writes metadata that your app understands?

Comment: That's a great idea. It does seem very time intensive, but certainly the way to go if I want to do this.

Comment: Firefox extensions are actually pretty simple to write. The Beagle project used to do what I imagine you're probably attempting: notify an external process about which URLs you're visiting. Maybe you can dig out some source from here: http://beagle-project.org/Browser_Extension