# How to find cache information in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, caching

I want to know where the cached information stored from `url: chrome://cache` in chrome browser.

where can I get it?

[Link cache in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlozU.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can find your Chrome temporary files:

Windows:

- Windows Vista: C:\Users[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\
- Windows XP: C:\Documents and Settings[USERNAME]\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\
- Windows 7/8: C:\Users[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache

Mac OS X:

- Open finder, hit Command+Shift+G, and type in /Users/[USERNAME]/Library/Caches/Google/Chrome/

and you can download chrome cash viewer [from here](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chrome_cache_view.html)

Comment: Thanks you very much. I found that folder and see in this folder have some file: index, data_* and f_*. With f_* , it have format is GZIP, so I can read It. But with file data_* and index, I can't open it. Do you know how to read it. (Now I'm programming a tool, so I dont want to use another tool for view cache). can you help me?

Comment: try this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310501/how-do-i-read-the-cache-of-chrome-and-firefox-programmatically-on-the-mac

Comment: Thanks you. Now I can read it after I read http://forensicswiki.org/wiki/Chrome_Disk_Cache_Format

Comment: @ThọNguyễnĐức can you share your program with us ?

Answer (score -1):

In addition to @wael-mohamed's answer,
in mac

goto

`$ cd /Users/{user}/Library/Caches/Google`

replace the {search-text} below with what you are searching

`$ grep -r "{search-text}" Chrome`